# Would you please explain this statement please

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, electronics

***As the atoms of a material are brought closer together to form the crystal lattice structure, there is an interaction between atoms, which will result in the electrons of a particular shell of an atom having slightly different energy levels from electrons in the same orbit of an adjoining atom. The result is an expansion of the fixed, discrete energy levels of the valence electrons. In other words, the valence electrons in a silicon material can have varying energy levels as long as they fall within the band .***

how the electron could have a different energy from other electron of anoter atom, and how could this result in the expansion of thr energy level (isn't supposed that electrons are not found between the energy levels) and how could they expand.

Comment: no offence intended, but there a number of questions arising from that statement.  Would you consider editing your question to point out the part(s) you are having trouble with? You would get a faster answer that way  regards

Comment: hello, thanks for your question; however, could you try to make it clearer? What is the source? What exactly don't you understand? I've voted to close this for the moment.

Comment: So sorry not to be accurate, how the electron could have a different energy from other electron of anoter atom, and how could this result in the expansion of thr energy level (isn't supposed that electrons are not found between the energy levels) and how could they expand

Comment: The title of this question offers the reader no information as to what the question is about. Check out [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) for advice on writing good question titles.

Comment: Where is the first paragraph from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two atoms approach each other, there comes a point where it is no longer possible to describe the system as "two atoms".   Rather, it becomes "one molecule".  This is a gradual transition.  When the atoms are far away from each other, they behave like separate atoms: one wave function for the atom on the left and an identical atom on the right having the same spectrum of energy levels as the one on the left.

As they approach each other, the potential due to the left begins to be felt by the atom on the right.  Now the picture of separate atoms is no longer accurate.   One now has to talk of the wave function and energy levels of the single system comprising both atoms.  At first the interaction is small, so the energy levels are much the same as they were for the separate atoms.  Detailed calculation shows that the "molecule" has two closely spaced energy levels, one slightly higher in energy than that of the separate atom, and one slightly lower.  We say that the energy level has "split".  As the atoms get close to each other the splitting gets larger and larger.  If the system does bind into an actual molecule, the energy levels can become so scrambled that they lose any identification with the isolated atom.

When *many many* atoms come together to form a solid, much the same thing happens.  Except that the energy level splits not into two levels, but $N$ levels, where $N$ is the order of Avogadro's Number.  Instead of two levels separated by a gap, one ends up with a smeared out *band* of levels.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt at hand-waving over an effect that is not really explained in the statement you gave. In a periodic (lattice) arrangement of identical atoms, the wavefunctions of electrons can also be described as having the same periodicity. In fact, it is the best (in the sense of most practically useful) description for this sort of system. Then your actual electron densities result from a superposition of the waves that the lattice structure allows, e.g. repeating on every N-th lattice site and having sine or cosine shape. Every one has a (at least) subtly different energy as a consequence, but lots of them are filled because there are lots of electrons. In the limit of assuming an infinitely large lattice, instead of lots of discrete but dense energy levels, they merge to form continuous bands of allowable energies for electrons, interrupted by forbidden energy ranges.

Comment: Would you explain more

Comment: No. I'm sorry, but unless you give an indication what you struggle with or what exactly interests you, that would be so aimless, I might as well write a book.

Comment: So sorry not to be accurate, how the electron could have a different energy from other electron of anoter atom, and how could this result in the expansion of thr energy level (isn't supposed that electrons are not found between the energy levels) and how could they expand.

Comment: The trick is to realize that the association between an electron and an atom becomes meaningless. Electrons will delocalize as they and "their own" atom's neighbors are indistinguishable. That means there are lots of crystal-spanning delocalized modes of electron occupancy contributing to your picture of atom-local electron density. Electrons never sit "between" the energy levels, but with a number of modes on the order of Avogadro's constant, it looks very nearly as if there then is an energy level everywhere within specific ranges, the energy bands.

Comment: I dont understand "That means there are lots of crystal-spanning delocalized modes of electron occupancy contributing to your picture of atom-local electron density"

Comment: You can only understand electrons in crystals by realizing the eigenfunctions/eigenvectors of their Hamiltonian are spread out over the entire crystal. That means that in a sense, electrons are delocalized, each having its own state (or mode as I wrote above), for lots of such states/modes in total. You can naturally translate to a view of localized electrons, which can be useful in some contexts, but that just means that you temporarily combine different of the crystal-spanning delocalized states in a way to describe the same physical situation.